# initWithFrame with self.view.frame : is it necessary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I was wondering what was the real meaning of using initWithFrame with this scrollView, because we also set the dimensions of the scrollView after that, and we add the scrollView as a subView of the view.

So why do we need to specify this initWithFrame? I actually don't really understand it when the frame is self.view.frame (I would understand it better if we set a different rectangle, such as 0,0 50,50)

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(847, 1129);
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Thanks

Comment: You should call initWithFrame passing in `self.view.bounds`, not `frame`.

Comment: Indeed, if self.view.frame has a non-zero origin then your scrollview will be offset by the same amount, probably not what you want. A child that fills its parent view should have its frame set to parentView.bounds.

Comment: @Mike Weller : okay, thanks, is it always the case, to specify initWithFrame with uiimageView or uiscrollView? i'm a bit confused because i assume the "child" knows its parent bounds... edit: also, in which case do we see the frame with a non-zero origin?

Comment: You always need to set a frame, otherwise the default will be CGRectZero so the view will not be visible because its width and height are zero. A UIImageView is a bit different however because it will automatically adjust its size when you set its image. However you still need to set the origin (x, y) of its frame to change exactly where it is located in the parent view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.view` in this case is the view containing the scrollview, so the scrollview fills the entire view when set to `self.view.frame`. Frame and content size are different things - frame of scrollview defines visible part of scrollview, and content size defines the size of scrollable (zoomable) content inside your scrollview.

Comment: thanks, yeah i understood the contentsize, so if we set a toolbar for example at the top, the scrollview will hide it by setting self.view.frame? ("fills the entire view") i'm a bit confused with self.view.bounds or .frame, and why it is necessary to use it. Thanks again

Comment: If toolbar/navbar/tabbar is displayed by controller higher in the hierarchy, then no, scrollview (or any other subview in current view) won't hide it because current view shrinks to what's left after all the bars been displayed. As for bounds and frames - if it says `initWithFrame:` - use parent view's frame, self.view.frame in this case. Or you can build interface visually in Interface Builder (which I prefer for non-dynamic interfaces).